# Access 2010 SQL Query: Finding above average winnings with data joined across 3 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, average, multiple-tables

My assignment wants a really specific query to be done in Access 2010. I've been pulling my hair trying to get/find a solution.

The assessment want me to create a list/query that will only show the career winnings of a horse that is better than that of the average. Except the data is split between the three tables listed below. I have created a query that can add the winnings together from the Prize and Entry tables but only for the Horse_id 's that exist in both the Horse and Entry Tables.

The problem is that they want the horses that haven't won any prizes to be included in the average calculation. But since those horses don't have a win record in the entry table it does not show those horses in the results for the *horsemon* query due the the inner join which is on the entry table because of that table being in the middle of the transaction.

**Query Name: Horsemon (I will change this later)**

```
SELECT horse.horse_id, horse.name, Sum(prize.money) AS moneysum FROM prize INNER JOIN (horse INNER JOIN entry ON horse.[horse_id] = entry.[horse_id]) ON prize.[place] = entry.[place] GROUP BY horse.horse_id, horse.name;
```

**Current Result:**

```
horse_id    name    moneysum
101        Flash    2460
102         Star    625
201        Boxer    1269
301        Daisy    725
```

I also created a second query that links into the first query that only shows the results above average. I am not sure how to achieve a Full Outer Join on the first query.

**Query Name: Horsemonavg**

```
SELECT horse.horse_id, horse.name, Sum(horsemon.moneysum) AS totalwinnings FROM horsemon INNER JOIN horse ON horsemon.horse_id = horse.horse_id WHERE (((horsemon.moneysum)>(SELECT AVG(moneysum) FROM horsemon))) GROUP BY horse.horse_id, horse.name;
```

**Current Result**

```
horse_id    name    totalwinnings
101         Flash   2460
```

Does anyone know what type of join to change the first query (horsemon) to also show the horses that haven't had any wins in the entry table work with all 3 tables of information to execute the average query? This is a lot more complicated then a join between 2 tables. Table data is below.

*Horse Table*

```
horse_id    name              colour    sire        dam        born  died   Gender

101        Flash               white     201        301        2001        s
102        Star                brown     201        301        2002        m
201        Boxer               grey      401        501        1991        s
301        Daisy               white     401        502        1992        m
401        Snowy               white     9999       9998       1987  1995  s
501        Bluebell            grey      9999       9998       1986  1993  m
502        Sally               white     9999       9998       1985  1998  m
9998       Unknown dam                   9999       9998       2000        m
9999       Unknown sire                  9999       9998       2000        s
```

*Entry Table*

```
event_id   horse_id   place
101        101        1          
101        102        2          
101        201        3          
101        301        4          
102        201        2          
103        201        3          
201        101        1          
301        301        2          
401        102        7
```

*Prize Table*

```
event_id    place      money
 101        1          120        
 101        2          60         
 101        3          30         
 102        1          10         
 102        2          5          
 102        3          2          
 103        1          100        
 103        2          60         
 103        3          40         
 401        1          1000       
 401        2          500        
 401        3          250        
 401        4          100        
 401        5          50
```

Comment: So the average calculation = total sum of winnings for all horses / total number of all horses (Not just winners)?

Comment: Yes, that is what the assignment says. The calculation must include horses that have not won any prize to do the average, which I can't get due to Access only allowing me to do an inner join as I need to also show the horses that haven't won before I do the second query.

Comment: So, using your tables, it would be 5079 / 9 ?

Comment: Yes that would be correct.